# button_to with remote: :true ends up redirecting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm attempting to create a button for a form that allows the user to save the entered data without redirecting/reloading or anything.

I've added a `button_to` to my form partial as follows:

```
<%= button_to "Update", incorporation_path(@incorporation), method: :post, remote: true %>
```

This does indeed save the data but submits the form with redirect and all.

Upon adding a `render :nothing => true` to the update controller method, I was simply confronted by a blank page when I clicked the button.  This is particularly surprising because I'd figured that the `remote: true` line would prevent this.

What might be up?

Any thoughts are appreciated

Comment: Does `remote: true` works everywhere else but not here?

Comment: @Yan_Foto fair question; yes it does

Comment: Do you see the `data-remote: true` attribute on the element?

Comment: Please provide a snippet of your form and take a look at answer below!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

You are talking about a form! Have you set the `remote: true` on `form_for`? Because that's how you submit a form asynchronously.

**Original answer**

`remote: true` is a part of [**Unobtrusive scripting adapter for jQuery**](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs). As the name implies this approach is *unobtrusice* and will not work if JS is deactivated or the library is not loaded. So make sure that you have the following lines in your script file:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

Comment: To your update:  Ah, I believe I haven't.  I'll check and get back to you.  Many thanks.  Regarding your original: yes, both are in there